# ng-class for select depending on which option is selected

Tags: angularjs

Ng-click does not work on an option so I am wondering how it might be possible to change the Select class depending on which option is selected.

```
  <select ng-class="paymentStatus ? 'Authorized' : 'Capture'">
                    <option>Authorized</option>
                    <option>Capture</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: Set a variable to be the name of the selected option. Then add css classes with the same name. Change the variable when you click on the option.  Add the variable to the select with ng class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to track what option is selected. Rather than defining your options, use `ng-options` and assign the `<select>` a model.

```
<body ng-app="TestApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <select ng-model="paymentStatus"
            ng-options="options for options in opts"
            ng-class="paymentStatus == 'Authorized' ? 'authorized' : 'capture'">
    </select>  
  </div>
</body>
```

Your ng-class what close, but you cant just test if its set or not. If its == to "Authorize", set the class to `authorize` else set it to `capture`

In your controller, you set what the default paymentStatus is

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp',[]);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope)
{
  $scope.opts = ['Authorized','Capture'];
  $scope.paymentStatus = $scope.opts[0];
});
```

and your css can be something like this:

```
.authorized {
  background-color:green
}

.capture {
  background-color:red
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7Lvw3jz/)

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing something similar. Since there will only be two options we just let the model in the controller tell it what to do

   <select ng-class="order.paymentStatus">
                        <option>Authorized</option>
                        <option>Capture</option>
                    </select>